# Redux relation between component, container and mapDispatchToProps,mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I read [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.vipq8vwg9) and [Smart and Dumb Components in React](http://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/)

And the concept :

```
components for “dumb” React components ;  
containers for “smart” React components ;
```

But they did not mention the `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`

Is it means I should get `state` and `action` from container and do not use `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` in components???
Or means I can use `mapDispatchToProps` but do not use `mapDispatchToProps` in components???

I felt confused about this component, container concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Presentational Component defines how things look and shouldn't be connected to the store. Here is an example of a Presentational/Dumb component:

```js
import React from "react"
import styles from "./styles.css"

const TodoList = ({ todos, removeTodo }) => (
  <div className={ styles.todoList }>
    { ... }
  </div>
)

export default TodoList
```

A Container defines how things work and you shouldn't put DOM markup or styles in this kind of component. It's connected to the store and only provides data to Presentational/Dumb components. Here is an example of a Container/Smart component:

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { removeTodo } from "actions/todos"
import TodoList from "components/TodoList"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: state.todos,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  removeTodo(todoId) {
    dispatch(removeTodo(todoId))
  },
})

const TodoListContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default TodoListContainer
```

So, to answer your question, you shouldn't use `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` in Presentational/Dumb components.

Comment: This answer really clarified the idea for me, thanks. Just one question, I am supposed to call TodoListContainer to render the TodoList, shouldn't TodoListContainer be a component with a render method? I am missing how to render it basically.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice article on redux
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-redux-makes-sense-to-me-and-how-i-conceptualize-it-c8a3a9db15ca#.5na6nr60l